# couldnot use rwclient in Oracle report builder 12c

Tags: oracle-fusion-middleware

I installed in my machine Oracle reprort builder 12c ( fusion middleware 12) and trying to use the tools **rwclient** to extracte pdf reports but I dount know my server name . also tried WLS_reports as server saind we could not stablish connection to the server.
how can I setup my server ?

whe I try they said we could not establish connection to the server ( I dont know where i can find the server exactly reponde to this feature)